# Haskell, Non-exhaustive patterns in function - way for checking this condition

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, non-exhaustive-patterns

Is there exist any way to check if my code contains: `Non-exhaustive patterns in function` ? Maybe some flag for compiler ?

Comment: Yes: `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` or simply `-Wall`.

Comment: Also maybe `-fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns`, which is not included in `-Wall`, if you're worried about patterns in lambdas.

Comment: @zakyggaps You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Anyway, all compilers for all languages have the `-Wall` option that turns on most warnings. You should compile with that option set. You could even use the `-Werror` flag which will make compilation fail whenever a warning is issued (sometimes you can ignore some warnings, so it may not be applicable to all cases).

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: @Bakuriu Sorry. I was searching for a duplicate but didn't find one.

Comment: Easy way to see all the options available: open ghci, type `:set -` and hit tab. This is the options for interpreting, not compiling, but all of the "warning" flags are shared between the two, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` or simply `-Wall`.

As @badcook hinted in the comment, if you want GHC to also warn non-exhausive patterns in lambdas you should add `-fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns`.